# Unable to get any response from a MongoDB connection on a Node.js server running on VPS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, vps, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to my MongoDB Cluster on a Node.js server. It works fine locally but not on the VPS I have purchased from Hostinger. The monitoring tools of the Cluster report activity, but I get no response. It does not return even an error message.

```
const uri = "…";

require("mongodb").MongoClient.connect(uri, { "useUnifiedTopology": true }, function(error, client) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return response.sendStatus(503);
    }
    else {
        // …
    }
});
```

The function does not even get called. I've waited for a while now without response. The VPS runs on Ubuntu 20.04. I am not familiar with the operating system or VPSs in general, but I did check if it had a firewall enabled. It does not appear to have “ufw” installed. Could it be the whitelist of the Cluster? It includes “0.0.0.0/0”, which I believe should actually allow every single IP address. I even tried adding the IP address of the VPS. Unfortunately, it did not help, but again, this is not something I often do. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Check your MongoDB cluster's IP whitelist: As you mentioned, your MongoDB cluster's IP whitelist should allow connections from any IP address